# Get new DataFrame with string column values replaced conditionally

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry for this easy question, can't quite figure it out.

I have a DataFrame (there are other columns which I want to keep):

```
0          ROBBERY            
1          THEFT              
2          CRIM SEXUAL ASSAULT
3          ASSAULT            
4          ASSAULT            
            ...               
1324690    THEFT              
1324691    CRIMINAL TRESPASS  
1324692    CRIMINAL DAMAGE    
1324693    CRIMINAL TRESPASS  
1324694    CRIMINAL DAMAGE    
Name: Primary Type, Length: 1324695, dtype: object
```

I want a new DataFrame with the same values, except replacing all values in a column if they're not in a provided list e.g.

```
print (len(crime_df))
print (crime_df["Primary Type"])

allowed_field_values = ['BATTERY', 'THEFT', 'NARCOTICS']

# Return this DataFrame, replacing all "Primary Type" column values with "OTHER" if they're not in the list
df = crime_df.loc[~crime_df["Primary Type"].isin(allowed_field_values), "Primary Type"] = "OTHER"

print (len(df))
print (crime_df["Primary Type"])
print (df["Primary Type"])

assert(len(df) == len(crime_df))
```

This outputs:

```
1324695
0          ROBBERY            
1          THEFT              
2          CRIM SEXUAL ASSAULT
3          ASSAULT            
4          ASSAULT            
            ...               
1324690    THEFT              
1324691    CRIMINAL TRESPASS  
1324692    CRIMINAL DAMAGE    
1324693    CRIMINAL TRESPASS  
1324694    CRIMINAL DAMAGE    
Name: Primary Type, Length: 1324695, dtype: object


5


0          OTHER
1          THEFT
2          OTHER
3          OTHER
4          OTHER
           ...  
1324690    THEFT
1324691    OTHER
1324692    OTHER
1324693    OTHER
1324694    OTHER
Name: Primary Type, Length: 1324695, dtype: object
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-207-4599b4364781> in <module>()
      9 print (len(df))
     10 print (crime_df["Primary Type"])
---> 11 print (df["Primary Type"])
     12 
     13 assert(len(df) == len(crime_df))

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: What is not working here? This looks correct.

Comment: It seems to be replacing the values in the original dataset and returning something with 5 elements and isn't a DataFrame...

Comment: Show the output please, and is that the output of the last line?

Comment: @Erfan Updated question, thanks.

Comment: Maybe `np.where` (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) can be useful for this case

Comment: Remove the `df =` before the line `crime_df.loc[~crime_df["Primary Type"].isin(allowed_field_values), "Primary Type"] = "OTHER"`, then put a line underneath, `df = crime_df`

Comment: @Erfan It still modifies the original collection, but making copy first works then modifying that is okay with me e.g.                                               `crime_copy_df = crime_df ;



crime_copy_df.loc[~crime_copy_df["Primary Type"].isin(allowed_field_values), "Primary Type"] = "OTHER"`